# How to get the selected node in the package explorer from an Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm writing an Eclipse command plugin and want to retrieve the currently selected node in the package explorer view. I want to be able to get the absolute filepath, where the selected node resides on the filesystem (i.e. c:\eclipse\test.html), from the returned result.

How do I do this ?

Answer (score 33):

The first step is to get a selection service, e.g. from any view or editor like this:

```
ISelectionService service = getSite().getWorkbenchWindow()
            .getSelectionService();
```

Or, [as VonC wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585802/how-to-get-the-selected-node-in-the-package-explorer-from-an-eclipse-plugin/585883#585883), you could get it via the PlatformUI, if you are neither in a view or an editor.

Then, get the selection for the Package Explorer and cast it to an IStructuredSelection:

```
IStructuredSelection structured = (IStructuredSelection) service
            .getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");
```

From that, you can get your selected IFile:

```
IFile file = (IFile) structured.getFirstElement();
```

Now to get the full path, you will have to get the location for the IFile:

```
IPath path = file.getLocation();
```

Which you then can finally use to get the real full path to your file (among other things):

```
System.out.println(path.toPortableString());
```

You can find more information on the selection service here: [Using the Selection Service](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-WorkbenchSelections/article.html).

Comment: "viewed 9 times"... nobody look those questions ;) Anyway, well detailed answer. +1

Comment: When getting the selection from the package explorer, the elements are not instances if IFile. You need to perform JDT->resource conversions.

Comment: @kberg The cast throws an exception indeed. But what do you mean perform JDT->resource conversion

Comment: Where is  "org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer" defined as a constant? Dont like magic strings.

Answer (score 16):

The code would be like:

```
IWorkbenchWindow window =
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
ISelection selection = window.getSelectionService().getSelection("org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PackageExplorer");
```

You view an example in an Action like this [**LuaFileWizardAction class**](http://svn.assembla.com/svn/Seq/luaeclipse/org.keplerproject.ldt.ui/src/org/keplerproject/ldt/ui/actions/LuaFileWizardAction.java).

Comment: Your link to LuaFileWizardAction class seems to be broken. It redirects to http://www.blackducksoftware.com/